# Round down and up between a range SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to know how to round up and down between in a range
example

from: .01 to .50 ROUND DOWN
to: .51 to .99 ROUND UP

100.41 will be 100
and
100.52 will be 101

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `ROUND` function:

```
SELECT ROUND(0.01, 0, null)    -- 0
SELECT ROUND(0.51, 0, null)    -- 1
SELECT ROUND(100.41, 0, null)  -- 100
SELECT ROUND(100.52, 0, null)  -- 101
```

If you want .5 to be rounded down, you should subtract .01 from your value, e.g.

```
DECLARE @var DECIMAL(10,2) = 0.5;
SELECT ROUND(@var - 0.01, 0, null) -- 0
```

Comment: No problem.  Consider accepting it as the answer if it solved your problem.

Comment: `select round(cast(0.5 as decimal), 0, null)` returns 1.  The OP wants 0.5 to round to 0.

Comment: Hmm.  I understood .5 to be exclusive, but maybe I misunderstood.  In that case, they could just do `select round(cast(0.5 as decimal) - 0.01,0,null)`